# How can I manage different firebase environments in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've been working on my app for a while now and its getting to move to prod and now I'm wondering how will I easily manage the future developments.
I'm looking for a way to switch between firebase projects depending on the environment I'm it.

thank you for your help

Comment: Well I guess google-services.json is the thing that gets changed for both projects. So if you are using git create a test branch and use the google-services.json for the test project there. (just dont stage the json file) while commiting.